# Can I use 74HC14 or NPN transistor instead of MOSFET as level shifter

Tags: arduino, i2c, raspberry-pi, level-shifting

I have [SN74HC14](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc14.pdf) or [BC548](http://www.philohome.com/sensors/gp2d12/gp2d12-datasheets/bc548.pdf) / [2N2222](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/PN/PN2222A.pdf) transistors. I need level shifter for I2C between arduino and RPi.
Here's simple circuit [from the internet](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf) [image]

Problem is I don't have any MOSFETs. Can I use NPN transistors instead? or do I better use 2 74HC14 NOT gates as single MOSFET?

Comment: Not easily, because unlike normal level shifter circuits, these signals must conduct in both directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use BJTs. Here is what I've built and it works (it has some disadvantages though and may not work in all cases):

[image]

Source: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2CBi-directionalLevelShifter

Comment: Can you say what disadvantages? or in what cases it will not work?

Comment: @a_vasilkov "If a line is pulled low, a current from the base to the emittor will turn that transistor on. But the other transistor will leak current from the base to the collector. That current will reduce the current in the first transistor. " from http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2CBi-directionalLevelShifter

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. The "trick" of using MOSFETs in this type of level shifter relies on the fact that MOSFETs are very symmetrical devices — for all practical purposes, the source and drain terminals can be interchanged, and the device works identically (ignoring the effects of the body diode).

BJTs do not have this symmetry property. The base-emiiter and base-collector junctions are deliberately made with different properties, and while you'll get *some* gain using it in the reverse direction, it's much less than using it in the proper direction.

The 74HC14 has pins that are input only and output only, and can't be used for bidirectional signals at all.

Comment: What do you mean by by symmetrical?

Comment: How a MOSFET can works two-sided (symmetrical)?