# Using NPN transistors for I2C level shifting

Tags: transistors, bjt, i2c, level-shifting

Background: I'm familiar with the method of level shifting an I2C signal using NMOS FETs and pull-up resistors. The Philips application note AN97055 documents the method and explains how it works here:  https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/an97055.pdf

[image]

My question is: Can you implement this same level-shifting scheme with an NPN transistor (2N2222, for example) in place of an NMOS FET?  A basic LTSpice simulation seems to show it would work, but something seems "wrong" about forcing current "backwards" through the NPN transistor when the 5.0V side gets pulled low.  I don't entirely trust the simulation results, and I don't have a lot of experience with transistor designs, so I don't have a good intuition for how this would work in practice:

[image: LTSpice Circuit]

[image: Plotted Signals]

Can anyone with experience with transistor designs comment on the concept?  Is my LTSpice simulation accurate, and would this transistor level shifter work in a real circuit?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117312/can-i-use-74hc14-or-npn-transistor-instead-of-mosfet-as-level-shifter ... Does that answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use 74HC14 or NPN transistor instead of MOSFET as level shifter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/117312/can-i-use-74hc14-or-npn-transistor-instead-of-mosfet-as-level-shifter)

Comment: The reverse hfe of modern bipolar transistors can be very low that will affect how well this will work.